# Multiple View Resolvers not working with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I use the following configuration of Thymeleaf for views as well as sending custom emails, it is not working

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver classLoaderTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.LEGACYHTML5.getTemplateModeName());
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/public/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.LEGACYHTML5.getTemplateModeName());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(webTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(classLoaderTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

View Resolution is working fine. But when I try to resolve a template by passing `org.thymeleaf.context.Context` to the template engine, following exception is thrown.

```
2017-10-06 13:36:27.962 ERROR 79725 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "resultPdf": Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]
    at org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver.getResourceAsStream(ServletContextResourceResolver.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:221) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:924) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:898) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Now since I have configured multiple template resolvers, the resolution should move on to the second one and `IWebContext` should not be required. 
So what shuold be the correct configuration for viee resolution as well as mail sending templates?

EDIT:
I am using `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` with spring boot 1.4.0

Comment: Why ar you configuring Thymeleaf manually... Spring Boot already configures that for you. Just drop this configuration. For your emails you should configure a dedicated template engine or satisfy all the resolvers by passing in a `IWebContext`.

Comment: I have a custom directory structure where templates get copied to. The directory is parallel to the `WEB-INF` folder. So need this config as else template engine cannot resolve templates.

Comment: Add properties to your `application.properties` to override/set the paths don't reconfigure everything. Also what you have here is also what is the default (`templates` and `public`). If you need an additional resolver, just add that resolver and it will be picked up and registered automatically. You don't need to override all the configuration.

Comment: I have a `index.html` file in `src/main/webapp/public`. If I remove the above config, it throws an error saying configured template resolvers cannot resolve the template

Comment: Have you read my comment? As stated only add the additional resolver don't reconfigure everything. Also the addition of that resolver will break the mail templates as it is now required to use a web based context for your view resolver. Hence configure a separate template engine for your emails. (imho you should also separate the mail en web views and they shouldn't be in the same location).

Comment: but you said `public` is already in the defaults. So if I don't configure anything, the file index.html should serve alright when I return a String "index" from controller. But that is not happening. Why?

Comment: No the `public` in `src/main/resources` is the default not `webapp` (the latter you shouldn't use imho).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156090/discussion-between-nikhil-sahu-and-m-deinum).